How to stop register cycling on deletions?
By default, vim cycles deleted contents to the small delete register or registers 1-9. I'd like to disable this (so that I can implement my cycling for yanks rather than deletions). I can figure out how to undo register cycling, but if register @9 has been pushed out of memory, I'm not quite sure how to recover it.
I feel like this should be possible with TextYankPost, but I couldn't quite figure it out.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Taking a hint from romainl's explanation that the solution has to be a hack, I've put the hack together for anyone else who like me, just wants to disable register cycling from deletions. One reason that I am very loathe to remap operations is that I am wary of it breaking my custom motions and custom operations.
This solution basically listens for when vim's register cycling kicks in, and manually undoes it, assuming that no script manually touches register @9 (which I've never seen any occasion for). It properly restores register types and <Nul> characters.
One point of note is that I'd like deletions to be kept only in the " unnamed register if possible (since I wanted to use all the number registers @[0-9] for my own yank ring), and so I've restored the @1 register to its state before the cycling as well. In doing so, I still need some register to contain the deleted data (as the unnamed register is just a pointer to another register, but not a "real" register), so I've decided to store the actual deletions in the "small deletion" register @- instead, and pointed the unnamed register to it. If this is not desired, simply comment out the first two calls to setreg.
let g:lastreg9conts = getreg('9', 1, 1)
let g:lastreg9type = getregtype('9')
function! Noregcycle(event) abort
    if a:event['operator'] != 'y'
        if a:event['regtype'] ==# 'V' || len(a:event['regcontents']) > 1
            call setreg ("", {'regcontents': getreg("", 1, 1), 'regtype': getregtype(""), 'points_to': '-'})
            call setreg('1', getreg('2', 1, 1), getregtype('2'))
            call setreg('2', getreg('3', 1, 1), getregtype('3'))
            call setreg('3', getreg('4', 1, 1), getregtype('4'))
            call setreg('4', getreg('5', 1, 1), getregtype('5'))
            call setreg('5', getreg('6', 1, 1), getregtype('6'))
            call setreg('6', getreg('7', 1, 1), getregtype('7'))
            call setreg('7', getreg('8', 1, 1), getregtype('8'))
            call setreg('8', getreg('9', 1, 1), getregtype('9'))
            call setreg('9', g:lastreg9conts, g:lastreg9type)
            endif
        endif
    endfunction

augroup noregcycle
    autocmd!
    autocmd TextYankPost * call Noregcycle(v:event)
    augroup end

(If anyone was wondering, my preferred yank ring is to do register cycling for yanks, and only yanks by default, and for non-yanks, to perform register cycling only when the user explicitly yanks into " or 0. Using the idea of the hack, my full solution looks like the following:
let g:lastreg0conts = getreg('0', 1, 1)
let g:lastreg0type = getregtype('0')
let g:lastreg1conts = getreg('1', 1, 1)
let g:lastreg1type = getregtype('1')
let g:lastreg9conts = getreg('9', 1, 1)
let g:lastreg9type = getregtype('9')
function! Yankring(event) abort
    let regname = "" .. a:event['regname']
    if a:event['operator'] == 'y'
        if (regname == '0') || (regname == '"') || (regname == "")
            let g:lastreg9conts = getreg('8', 1, 1)
            let g:lastreg9type = getregtype('8')
            
            call setreg('9', g:lastreg9conts, g:lastreg9type)
            call setreg('8', getreg('7', 1, 1), getregtype('7'))
            call setreg('7', getreg('6', 1, 1), getregtype('6'))
            call setreg('6', getreg('5', 1, 1), getregtype('5'))
            call setreg('5', getreg('4', 1, 1), getregtype('4'))
            call setreg('4', getreg('3', 1, 1), getregtype('3'))
            call setreg('3', getreg('2', 1, 1), getregtype('2'))
            call setreg('2', getreg('1', 1, 1), getregtype('1'))
            call setreg('1', g:lastreg0conts, g:lastreg0type)
            
            let g:lastreg1conts = g:lastreg0conts
            let g:lastreg1type = g:lastreg0type
            let g:lastreg0conts = getreg('0', 1, 1)
            let g:lastreg0type = getregtype('0')
            endif
    elseif (regname == '0') || (regname == '"')
        let g:lastreg9conts = getreg('8', 1, 1)
        let g:lastreg9type = getregtype('8')
        
        call setreg('9', g:lastreg9conts, g:lastreg9type)
        call setreg('8', getreg('7', 1, 1), getregtype('7'))
        call setreg('7', getreg('6', 1, 1), getregtype('6'))
        call setreg('6', getreg('5', 1, 1), getregtype('5'))
        call setreg('5', getreg('4', 1, 1), getregtype('4'))
        call setreg('4', getreg('3', 1, 1), getregtype('3'))
        call setreg('3', getreg('2', 1, 1), getregtype('2'))
        call setreg('2', g:lastreg1conts, g:lastreg1type)
        call setreg ("", {'regcontents': getreg("", 1, 1), 'regtype': getregtype(""), 'points_to': '-'})
        call setreg('1', g:lastreg0conts, g:lastreg0type)
        
        let g:lastreg1conts = g:lastreg0conts
        let g:lastreg1type = g:lastreg0type
        let g:lastreg0conts = getreg('0', 1, 1)
        let g:lastreg0type = getregtype('0')
    else
        if (a:event['regtype'] ==# 'V') || (len(a:event['regcontents']) > 1)
            call setreg ("", {'regcontents': getreg("", 1, 1), 'regtype': getregtype(""), 'points_to': '-'})
            call setreg('1', getreg('2', 1, 1), getregtype('2'))
            call setreg('2', getreg('3', 1, 1), getregtype('3'))
            call setreg('3', getreg('4', 1, 1), getregtype('4'))
            call setreg('4', getreg('5', 1, 1), getregtype('5'))
            call setreg('5', getreg('6', 1, 1), getregtype('6'))
            call setreg('6', getreg('7', 1, 1), getregtype('7'))
            call setreg('7', getreg('8', 1, 1), getregtype('8'))
            call setreg('8', getreg('9', 1, 1), getregtype('9'))
            call setreg('9', g:lastreg9conts, g:lastreg9type)
            endif
        endif
    endfunction

)

Using :help TextYankPost is definitely possible but it won't make anything magically simpler. Compare this:
nnoremap d <Cmd>call MyYankRing('d')<CR>
function! MyYankRing(operator) abort
    " the complicated stuff
endfunction

with this:
autocmd! TextYankPost call MyYankRing()
function! MyYankRing() abort
    " the complicated stuff
endfunction

You will still have to implement your own parallel yank ring and keep it in sync with the native yank ring via lots of :help getreg() and :help setreg(), which is almost certainly the most involved part of this problem.
--- EDIT ---
Register cycling can't be disabled. There is no option for that, or build flag. It is hardcoded and there is nothing you can do about it… except begging the maintainers to put it behind an option.
What you can do, though, is reimplementing the parts of the system that you care about. That is the " the complicated stuff in the samples above. Others have been there before and, if their efforts look to you like hacks, well, it is because they are. And there is a fair chance that yours or mine will, too.
When @9 is gone, it is gone for good. There is no way to recover it. If you want to keep @9, you will have to save it in some data structure of yours before it is gone, which can only be done by keeping that data structure and the numbered registers in sync. That is one of the reasons why you need your ds to use your own parallel yank ring instead of, or in addition to, the native one. Which means that, at some point, you might find yourself in a position where "remapping" all the operators doesn't look that silly anymore.

Thanks for your answer. I'm comfortable implementing register cycling by myself, and added that part of explanation as context, but it seems that it seems to lead people to believe that's the crux of my question. I'm really seeking help just for the part in disabling register cycling, and edited my question to reflect this.

@user22476690, That behavior can't be disabled, that's the whole point. Answer edited.

Understood. Thanks for your explanation.
